# sql select 3 columns and dedupe on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I have a job setup that currently selects records from a table that does not contain a  unique index. I realize this could be solved by just putting an index on the table and the relevant columns but, in this scenario for testing purposes, I need to remove the index and then do a  select which will also remove duplicates based on 2 columns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [author], [pubDate], [dateadded]
FROM [Feeds].[dbo].[socialPosts]
WHERE CAST(FLOOR(CAST(dateadded AS float)) AS datetime) > 
                               DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE() - 2), 0)  
AND CAST(FLOOR(CAST(dateadded AS float)) AS datetime) < 
                               DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

This selects all records from the day before and I want to dedupe the records based on author and pubdate. This could be a post select or done prior but the idea is to find out if it can be done within a select.

Comment: Are you actually storing `dateadded` as a _float_ value?  Why not an actual date/timestamp value?  Also, you should be doing lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive ranges (the `> - 2` bit is offputting).  What's the relationship between `dateadded` and the other columns - could a simple `MAX()` be used?

Comment: dateadded is actually stored as datetime...was not sure of any other way to get it to work...dateadded is the date for the particular record and I just need to get total records for the previous day

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything to your stored data - it's already 'correct'.  Leave off the casting (which can't be helping you any).  I'm not sure it's completely 'safe'.  Your upper bound should be fine as-is.  Your lower bound should be changed to `dateadded >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `GROUP BY` and any aggregate function on the `dateadded` column to get unique `author, pubdate` results.

```
SELECT  [author]
        ,[pubDate]
        ,MAX([dateadded])
 FROM   [Feeds].[dbo].[socialPosts]
 WHERE  CAST(FLOOR(CAST(dateadded AS float)) AS datetime) >  dateadd(day,datediff(day, 0, getdate()-2), 0)  
        AND CAST(FLOOR(CAST(dateadded AS float)) AS datetime) < dateadd(day,datediff(day, 0, getDate()), 0)
 GROUP BY 
        [author]
        , [pubdate]
```