# Deleting duplicate records with clustered primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SOURCE table and a TARGET table.
I want to delete duplicate records from the SOURCE table(or say I want to insert only DISTINCT records in the TARGET table) considering the combination of column a and b. Can someone please help.

```
CREATE TABLE #SOURCE (
    a        int NOT NULL,
    b        int NOT NULL,
    c        int NOT NULL,

);

INSERT INTO #SOURCE (a, b, c)
VALUES (1, 2, 3),
       (1, 3, 4), --either this record or the one below should be deleted
       (1, 3, 6),
       (3, 4, 5),
       (3, 5, 6),
       (5, 6, 7),
       (5, 7, 8), --either this record or the one below should be deleted
       (5, 7, 0)
       (6, 8, 9);

CREATE TABLE #TARGET (
    a        int NOT NULL,
    b        int NOT NULL,
    c        int NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (a, b)
);
```

So I need to delete the records from the SOURCE table (probably the ones I marked above in comments) or in other words as I said above, I want to only insert distinct records(a+b) in  TARGET table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql select 3 columns and dedupe on two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402025/sql-select-3-columns-and-dedupe-on-two-columns)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `ROW_NUMBER()` and a `PARTITION` on `A` and `B`:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By A, B Order By C) RN
    From    #SOURCE
)
Insert  #TARGET
        (A, B, C)
Select  A, B, C
From    Cte
Where   RN = 1
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. As I am comparatively new to SQL and trying to learn more, will you please be able to explain what your query is doing, specifically this part - Row_Number() Over (Partition By A, B Order By C) RN

Comment: The `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B ORDER BY C)` will assign a number to each grouping of the distinct `A`, `B` values and the incremental number assigned will be based on that order of the `C` value.  You can view the results of the `ROW_NUMBER()` by doing `SELECT * FROM Cte` instead of the `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't care which value of C gets put into the target just group by A,B, and select min/max of C.

```
Insert into #target select a,b,min(c) 
from #source 
group by A,B
```